# Modals don't load additional css

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have the problem after displaying the modal and close it and open another modal on the same page it doesn't load the .css files which are included in the modal.

/modal_page.php

```
              <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" id="addModal-external">

                    </div>
              </div>

              <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" id="editModal-external">

                    </div>
              </div>
```

```
<script>
        $(document).on("click", ".add_modal", function () {
        $("#addModal-external").load("../action/add/modal/add_modal");
        }); 
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".edit_modal", function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $("#editModal-external").load("../action/edit/modal/edit_modal?id=" + id);
        }); 
    </script>
```

/action/add/modal/add_modal

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/vendor/libs/select2/select2.css" />

<div class="modal-content p-3 p-md-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-pinned" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <h3 class="mb-2">New Modal</h3>
        </div>
        <form action="" class="row g-3" method="POST">        
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="selectCheck">Check</label>
                <select class="select2 form-select" id="selectCheck" name="selectCheck">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 text-center demo-vertical-spacing">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-sm-3 me-1">Create</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-label-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="../../../assets/vendor/libs/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="../../../assets/js/forms-selects.js"></script>
```

forms-selects.js

```
/**
 * Selects & Tags
 */

'use strict';

$(function () {
  const selectPicker = $('.selectpicker'),
    select2 = $('.select2'),
    select2Icons = $('.select2-icons');

  // Bootstrap Select
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (selectPicker.length) {
    selectPicker.selectpicker();
  }

  // Select2
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Default
  if (select2.length) {
    select2.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.wrap('<div class="position-relative"></div>').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select value',
        dropdownParent: $this.parent()
      });
    });
  }

  // Select2 Icons
  if (select2Icons.length) {
    // custom template to render icons
    function renderIcons(option) {
      if (!option.id) {
        return option.text;
      }
      var $icon = "<i class='" + $(option.element).data('icon') + " me-2'></i>" + option.text;

      return $icon;
    }
    select2Icons.wrap('<div class="position-relative"></div>').select2({
      templateResult: renderIcons,
      templateSelection: renderIcons,
      escapeMarkup: function (es) {
        return es;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The edit_modal looks similar to the add_modal.

After loading as example the add_modal everything works, but after that loading the edit_modal without refreshing the modal_page.php the select2 includes doesn't load.

I already tried to include the select2 things in the modal_page.php and remove them from the modals. But also don't work. What i do wrong? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Show live web project

Comment: `forms-selects.js` is your own custom script to initialize those select2 instances? Then show us what that contains.

Comment: @CBroe added in the post

Comment: `$(function () {}` fires when the DOM is fully loaded, not sure how that is supposed to behave when you use `.load` to insert this into another document.

Comment: @CBroe oh thanks. But it didn't change anything because the .css files of select2 doesn't load.

Comment: When you check the network tab in dev tools, does it attempt to load the CSS? what URL is it loading from (full path)? Is it returning a 404 or so, meaning it can't find it?

Comment: @cloned it loads the select2.js the forms-selects.js but not the select2.css after one load.
It isn't possible to load the select2.css multiple times.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to load the css twice. That's what caching is for. So if it is loaded once, you already have it applied to your page.

Comment: @cloned after closing the modal and reopening the modal it doesn't apply the select2.css content.